# Responding to custom event if raised from different classes

Tags: c#, events

This is more a design question, and I hope I express my question clear.
I have a complex process, that needs to log messages.  When some of these logs are written, a event is raised and I need to respond to this.

The problem is that the CreateLog method are called from different classes during the process and currently my code only catches the events raised from the first class (MyForm).

Is there a better design where I can respond to all events from that class?

Hopefully the pseudo code below will shed some light on my problem.

**File 1:**

```
Class CreateLog
{
   Log Message
   Raise event
}
```

**File 2:**

```
Class MyForm
{
   private CreateLog _log = new CreateLog();
   void StartProcess()
   {
       Do stuff
       Call _log.LogMessage  //1
       Call MethodB()
       Call MethodC()
   }

   void MethodB()
   { 
       Call _log.LogMessage  //2
   }

   void RespondToEvent
   {
       //Show Progress on screen
   }
}
```

**File 2:**

```
Class AnotherClass
{
    void MethodC()
    {
        _log2.LogMessage()  //3
    }
}
```

So, when I run this, the message log at nr 1 and 2 will fire the RespondToEvent() method, but obviously not at nr 3, because it's a different instance of the CreateLog class.
One solution is to pass _log as a parameter to MehodC, but that does not feel like the best solution.

Any other clean way of achieving this besides adding everything into 1 class?

Comment: If you have two different instances of the log class what prevents you to have two different event handlers to handle the log

Comment: Valid question: The class in File2 is a Winforms that needs to update a progress bar/table. File3 can be called from File2 and File4. File4 needs to update something else. So, yes, AnotherClass can have it's own event handler, but then it should behave differently depending from where it was called.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event to **AnotherClass** and raise that event in **MethodC**. And in **MyForm** handle the event and call _log.LogMessage

Example:

```
Class MyForm
{
    //your code

    RespondToEventFromAnotherClass()  //handles delegateToForm Event from 'AnotherClass'
    {
        Call _log.LogMessage
    }
}
Class AnotherClass
{
    Event delegateToForm;
    void MethodC()
    {
        _log2.LogMessages(); // you can Eleminate this line if it is not necessary
        Raise Event delegateToForm
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. It's a possibility.  Will try it.

Comment: Come to think of it, there are however more than 1 "AnotherClass".  That means MyForm, and MyForm2-x needs to subscribe to a couple of events. Can become "messy", but still an option, thanks.

Comment: Ya but you can make all 'AnotherClass'es subuscribe the same method. That will keep the code clean.